# Replicating Simpson's rule, error with eval

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to replicate the Simpson's rule by writing a function for it. However, I'm still not clear how I could possibly use eval to transform a string to a actual function in MatLab.

The function is:

```
function result = simpson(fun, x0, xn, n)
    f = eval(fun);
    h = (xn-x0)/2;
    xstart = f(x0) + f(xn);
    x1 = 0;
    x2 = 0;

    for i = 1:n-1
        x = x0 + h*i;
        if (mod(i,2) == 0)
            x2 = x2 + f(x);
        else
            x1 = x1 + f(x);
        end
    end

    result = h*(xstart + 2*x2 + 4*x1)/3;
```

The error reported is

```
Error using eval
Undefined function or variable 'x'
```

How could I pass x to a string form of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way to do that: Use a function handle, avoid eval.

Function handles are documented here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html

Define them like this:

```
sqr = @(x) x.^2;
```

and then call your function:

```
simpson(sqr, 1, 2, 3);
```

within your function, you should e able to call fun(3) and get 9 as a result.

---

If you *have to use eval*, I could see two solutions:

1. The Sneaky way:  `simpson('@(x) x.^2')` (eval creates a proper function handle)
2. The dirty way:

   ```
   function result = simpson(fun)
       x = 4;
       f = eval(fun);
       result = f;
       return;
   end
   ```

Call it like this: `simpson('x.^2')`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't answer my question. I know how to use function handles, just that I'm asked to solve this with eval().

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the way `eval` is being used. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) indicates that in your example the output `f` would not be a function handle (as is expected by the way the code uses it), but rather the output of the `fun` function.

So, in order to make the `eval` function work you need to provide it with it's input.

For example:

```
fun = 'x.^2';    
x = 4;    
f = eval(fun);
```

Results in `f == 16`

In short, any time you wish to call `fun` you would have to set `x` to the appropriate value, call eval and store the result.

For example, in your code:

```
f = eval(fun);
h = (xn-x0)/2;
xstart = f(x0) + f(xn);
```

Would become:

```
h = (xn-x0)/2;
x = x0;
fx0 = eval(fun);
x = xn; 
fxn = eval(fun);
xstart = fx0 + fxn;
```

I would suggest function handles as a safer and easier way of implementing this, but as mentioned in the comments this is not allowed in your case.